# Try open files and exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

```
def abrir_archivo(nombre_archivo):
    try:
        archivo = open(nombre_archivo, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("El archivo no fue encontrado")
    except:
        print("Error desconocido")
    else:
        print("Abriendo exitosamente")
    finally:
        print("Finalizando ejecucion")

abrir_archivo(1)
```

When I run the program, the else line is executed and prints "Opening Successfully", this happens with the numbers 0, 1 and 2. My question is why? Isn't it supposed to give an error? When I pass 3 or -1 or any other number, it does print "Unknown error"
(I speak Spanish, if something is not understood... google translate is guilty uu)

Comment: Have you checked your directory if you have files called `0`, `1`, or `2`? Also, for `open(file, mode)`, `file` and `mode` are supposed to be string(`str`), but it looks like you are passing a number (`int`) instead. Perhaps that is causing problems?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function accepts a file descriptor as the `file` argument when it's an integer, and per [POSIX standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), 0, 1 and 2 correspond to the standard input, standard output and standard error, respectively:

```
with open(1, 'w') as stdout:
    stdout.write('foo') # outputs foo to standard output
```

You may programmatically obtain the file descriptor by calling the [`fileno`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.fileno) method of the file object:

```
import sys

with open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w') as stdout:
    stdout.write('foo') # outputs foo to standard output
```

Other integer numbers may be accepted if it represents an open file descriptor.